# I want to know where the error in my calculations ! :(

Tags: c++

I'm new in c++ programming. I tried to solve this question but I can't find the formula to Calculate the sum.

> Write a program to estimate how much a young worker will make before retiring at age of 65. Request the worker's name, age, and starting salary as input. Assume the worker receives a 5 percent raise each year. For example, if the user enters Helen, 25 and 20000, the output will be:
>   Helen will earn about $2415995

This is my formula:

```
for(age;age<=65;age++)
{
    sum=sum+stSalary+(5/100);
}
```

when the for loop finish I printed the sum but it's value is wrong.

Comment: This is more of a basic math problem than a programming problem, your percent caluclation is off. You probably want to multiply stSalary by 1.05 and save that value for the next iteration.

Comment: You also need to use doubles, not integer division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i = age; i < 65; i++)
{
     sum = sum + stSalary;
     stSalary = stSalary * 1.05;
}
```